# Cracking simple RSA when just the ciphertext and one public key is known

Tags: rsa, brute-force-attack

Can someone explain to me (Or better yet, point me to a tool that does the brute forcing) how to crack a standard, simple RSA cipher (So don't bother with padding) if I know just one public key, the ciphertext, and some text that I know for sure is part of the plaintext?

Please don't point me to the Wikipedia article or something, I'm trying to get a simple explanation that is fully understandable.

Comment: Hint: if what you don't know about the plaintext is small enough, you can guess it, and check your guess. Other attacks might apply depending on parameters unstated in the question.

Comment: Unpadded RSA is simple, or at least simpler, but it is definitely NOT STANDARD because it is a Very Bad Idea to use it for anything, ever.

Comment: Depending on the situation you might also have e=3 and without padding you might then be able to decrypt the ciphertext by simply taking the cube root.

Answer (score 1):

Running RSA backwards would imply cracking the key (determining the private key) and you could brute force that by factoring.  You could generate all possible prime's of the requisite size until you could generate the known public key.  Or perhaps there are other approaches that are more mathematical, that could factor for the primes, which would also be a form of brute force, as currently factoring is thought to be a NP-hard problem.

Comment: (The decision version of) integer factorisation is believed to not be NP-hard (which is not the same thing as being in NP).